# Source for a minyan while davening?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, minyan

The patriarchs and Hannah, after whom we model our davening, all davened alone. From where do we learn the strong preference for davening with a minyan? Also, there always was a minyan in the Temple. From where do we learn the reason for a minyan in the Temple? Did any or all of the korbanot require a minyan?  Is our davening with a minyan today related to the minyan in the Temple?

Comment: the answers here cite some sources http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/19080/what-is-the-benefit-to-praying-with-a-minyan

Comment: "there always was a minyan in the Temple" Source for that? On Yom Kippur for instance it was just one person inside.

Comment: @DoubleAA Inside where?

Comment: @YehudaW The Temple. See http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0316.htm#17

Comment: @DoubleAA The Tent of Meeting was not the same as the Temple. Your statement used the term Temple. What support do you have for your statement " just one person inside"?

Comment: @YehudaW In the Temple, the same rule applies (see Yoma 43b for parameters). No one else was in there with him.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the source for the minyan is mentioned in Talmud Brachot. Isn't there a lengthy discussion stating that  *davar shebikedusha** ("holy matters") such as public Torah reading, require an assembly of 10 men? Is there something that I'm missing from your question?

Comment: @DoubleAA  I was thinking of Sanhedrin 17B but, on rereading it, perhaps the men of leisure only applied to synagogues.

Comment: @DoubleAA Your reference to Yoma 43b prompts me again to ask, "Inside where?" Inside the Ulam? Inside the Gate of Nikanor? Or inside the entire walled area, including the ezras nashim the seat of the minor sanhedrin, and the 4 rooms described in Yoma on 16a?

Comment: @YehudaW I believe the Rambam rules that no one else can be in the Heikhal at the time. Why does that matter exactly? He's doing Avoda alone.

Comment: @DoubleAA  I was just trying to clarify the matter. In any case, the vacating must have been done quickly since collecting the blood must have required more than one person.

Comment: @YehudaW The collecting of the blood happened outside in the Azara, not in the Heikhal.