# Sources from Tanach for Praying in Minyan

Tags: commentaries, tzibur-community, korbanos-ketores-prayers

I’ve got a question about people praying together.

1. Hence from were in the Tanach, from which verse(s) or context, did the idea or concept for group/communal/collective prayer developed from? Or is it only of rabbinic origin? I heard it is a public service replacing the public sacrifices that were made in the Temple in biblical times. Is this true and/or are there other reasons from a biblical perspective for such prayers, i.e. getting together and pray.
2. Is there a ‘need’ to pray together, what does the Tenach teach us, what’s the benefit in regards to singular prayer. Are such prayers more powerful/meaningful than an individual praying alone?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11113/davening-with-a-minyan https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12319/importance-of-minyan? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76469/source-for-a-minyan-while-davening https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28935/must-one-pray-with-a-minyan?r=SearchResults

Comment: and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/19080/759

Comment: @rosends thanks for all the links most of those provided an answer on my second question, but I’m still looking for sources based on Tenach or verses/context from Tenach which shows or teach about prayer with/between two or more people; I’m looking for clear proof that it’s meaningfull, that our forefathers did the same. From a human perspective and from a social standpoint (connecting, sharing, binding) it’s clearly meaningfull, but I’m looking for something in the Tenach which affirms this which agrees with it. I’m looking for something which shows me it was done on a regular basis.

Comment: A clear duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76469/source-for-a-minyan-while-davening

Comment: @AlBerko regards my second question, I agree that’s a duplicate, but regards the first I have some doubts. The difference is that in the question you refered to already assumes things where I ask for the sources (from the Tenach), the fundament for praying together in general.

Comment: I noticed Brachot 26b states one opinion that prayer came from the forefathers, while another refers to the Temple service. From this you can see different essences of prayer, one refers to a more intimate and private and personal prayer while the other sees prayer as a continuation of the sacrafices in the Temple. Which fits my idea of public sacrifices as a example and reason for communal prayer. It also shows some discussion on how prayer was established, hence from where we derive the concepts of individual and non-individual prayer. I’m looking for more of these sources and proofs.

Comment: I should remind you, that all the prayers are Derabanan, see Rambam Tefila. Therefore you can't find a Source from Tanach, although you can find Asmachtah that the Sages used to institute the prayers in Minyan, as in Berochos. You might want to understand the difference between a source and Asmachtah better.